# Text Maching issues

Tags: php, mysql

im using Full-text search to retrive some data, in my case matches, but im having some issues regarding with it. For example there will be terms that are not exactlly how is inserted but it exists on the db.
The structure is always "nameteam" - "nameteam"

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM matches
WHERE MATCH(search_match) AGAINST ('Bielorrússia - Hungria');
```

I have 2 same records that should be returned, but only gives me one.

records:

```
'Bielorrússia - Hungria'
and
'Bielorússia - Hungria'
```

There will be other similiar situations with this, but i need a way of retrieving all the records and not the exact match, is there a better way?

Comment: i dont understand what your saying

Comment: Now I understand what you need, Somthing Like below
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE '%Bielorússia%' AND `name` LIKE '%Hungria%'